# Can not select information of date in query made before

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework, datetime

I want to show information of employees who have birthday from now to next to a given day.

This is my queries. function with _dayrm is parameter

```
Dim query = (From emp In Context.UNI_EMPLOYEE_CV.ToList
                         Select New RemindDTO With {
                             .EMPLOYEE_CODE = emp.UNI_EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_CODE,
                             .FULLNAME = emp.UNI_EMPLOYEE.FULLNAME,
                             .REMIND_DATE = emp.BIRTHDATE}).ToList.Distinct

Dim result = (From emp In query
                             Where emp.REMIND_DATE IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                             ((DateTime.Now >= New Date(DateTime.Now.Year, emp.REMIND_DATE.Value.Month, emp.REMIND_DATE.Value.Day).AddDays(-_dayrm)) And
                             (DateTime.Now <= New Date(DateTime.Now.Year, emp.REMIND_DATE.Value.Month, emp.REMIND_DATE.Value.Day)))
                             Select emp)

Return result.ToList()
```

i used entityframwork and oracle database

but it has an error in "Select p" with message "Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime."

Comment: I am not sure why you are mixing DateTime.Now (year) and emp.REMIND_DATE.Value (month and day) to build a date but it seems like the emp.REMIND_DATE.Value part is getting values completely off (example: 0 or 13 for month). Check your input data.

Comment: REMIND_DATE is a Date type so i think it can not be 13 in month like you mentioned in your example...

Comment: This is what the error you are referring is indicating (one of these two values has to be wrong; DateTime.Now.Year should be OK). There are many reasons which might be provoking that the value is wrong, for example: you are accounting for different regional settings; 1/13/2000 is acceptable for US (month/day), but not in quite a few European countries (day/month). The problem is clearly in the inputs and your code does not provide any hint on this front and thus is very difficult to know what is going on.

Comment: i know what you mean, but when i debug and observe the value of DateTime.Now.Year. it showed 2013 exactly but there is not value were shown in emp.REMIND_DATE.Value.Month and Date while the results of first query is "Dim query" showed the value of REMIND_DATE exactly with database in oracle

Comment: You are not clarifying anything. DateTime.Now is fine for sure and, in any case, is constant. The variables taking different values during the query are emp.REMIND_DATE.Value.Month and emp.REMIND_DATE.Value.Day and you should check those: either by looking at the values in the original DB or by creating a new query just for debugging writing down all the values to a text file or something like this. If you don't provide further information about the input conditions (i.e., all the values which emp.REMIND_DATE.Month and emp.REMIND_DATE.Day take), we cannot help you.

Comment: i ensure that all values in my DB are correct. and the the problem in "Dim result" query b/c it can't get value of REMIND_DATE to assign to new date. Thanks for what you've done for me @varocarbas

Comment: You don't even need to look at the query. The error is very descriptive: you are defining a date variable with wrong inputs. The error is undoubtedly provoked by REMIND_DATE Dim result = (From emp In query iterates through all the records and thus you have to debug the input information and to make sure that the values are the expected ones, for example, by adapting this query to write to a text file. I haven't been of too much help because you haven't allowed me to know what is right/wrong (= list of REMIND_DATE.Value.Day and REMIND_DATE.Value.Month) but you are welcome anyway.

Comment: @user2494355 - You do realize that with all of those `ToList` calls, you are pulling down your entire table and operating in memory, right?  Also, you should just get `DateTime.Now` once.  Every time you call it you are getting a new value from the system clock.

Comment: @MattJohnson - I really don't know what you mean. I tried to do this: 'Dim new_date as DATE = DateTime.Now' and change DateTime.Now in result query to new_date. But i still error at a person who has birthday "2/29/1960".

Comment: i have just knew one thing from the "Every time you call it you are getting a new value from the system clock" of you @MattJohnson and why i should just get DateTime.Now once? b/c when i change the parameter of New Date from Datetime.Now.Year in twice times i call it, it runs ok.... thanks for helpful information

Comment: what is problems if i use DateTime.Now more than once? could you give me a solution to change it to current year in result query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to think about how this operation is going to be handled by your database.  In your current code, because you are calling `ToList` at the end of the first line, the only query made to your database is something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM UNI_EMPLOYEE_CV
```

Everything that follows `ToList` is being done in memory.  In other words, you are retrieving the *entire* table.

So what query *should* you execute on your database?  Well, that gets a bit tricky.  In order to have good performance, all queries should be able to use an index.  Otherwise, they have to scan the entire table.  In general, any time you write a query that has to modify the field in the database before comparing it, that's a query that will have to scan every row of the table.  In some cases, it may scan every row of an *index*, but that is also not good. You want a *seek*, not a *scan*.

So take a step back and think about what you are doing.  You want to query for all employees who's birthday falls into a particular range.  But since it is their birthday *this year*, you don't have a column that you can create an index on.  Every row would have to have it's data adjusted to the current year.

This is discussed in detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9861529/634824).  I think the best solution is [the one by MatBailie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9861727/634824).  Basically, you need to create an additional column and populate it with data where the year is fixed to 2000.  Then you need to index that column.  (I am not an Oracle expert, but I believe you could also do this with an index on a Materialized View, if you can't change the table schema.  In SQL Server you could use an Indexed View.)

So let's assume that you have done this, and you now have a column called `BIRTHDAY_Y2K` in your database.  Now you can do this:

```vbnet
Dim today As DateTime = DateTime.Today
Dim startDate As DateTime = new DateTime(2000, today.Month, today.Year)
Dim endDate As DateTime = startDate.AddDays(_dayrm)

If endDate.Year = 2000 Then

    Dim query = (From emp In Context.UNI_EMPLOYEE_CV
                 Where emp.BIRTHDAY_Y2K >= startDate
                   And emp.BIRTHDAY_Y2K <= endDate
                )
Else

    endDate = endDate.AddYears(-1)

    Dim query = (From emp In Context.UNI_EMPLOYEE_CV
                 Where emp.BIRTHDAY_Y2K >= startDate
                    Or emp.BIRTHDAY_Y2K <= endDate
                )
End If
```

The reason for the split is to cover scenarios such as running on December 20 for 30 days and still catching birthdays like Jan 10th.

I think you can take it from here to complete each query.  You should only have one `ToList()` call at the very end of each before the data is returned from your method.

Also, just to answer some of the questions from your earlier comments:

- You are having problems with Feb 29 dates because it only exists in leap years.  Assigning Feb 29 to an arbitrary year will fail if the year is not a leap year.  Since we used year 2000 in the above code, it will be safe for Feb 29 birthdays.
- You don't want to call `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.Today` more than once in an operation, because it has to read from the system clock each time you call it.  Since the clock is always ticking away, you risk problems if the days change between one call and the next.  It's a bad practice in general, and can also lead to performance problems in some operations.

Comment: thanks so much @Matt Johnson, the problem is in the leap years and i already have solution for this..........

Answer (score 0):

Oracle datetime format are different. Use to_date function to pass it in the required format and then use it to manipulate in your query.

Comment: Are different than what? This is a .NET error triggered when you intend to build a date from wrong numbers (e.g., 0-13-0001). OP's code is not passing an Oracle Date, but just using some integers from it (day, month). Can you please elaborate more on what you mean and how your statement is expected to be of any help?